# How to draw a mask line on a FFT magnitude spectrum

Tags: python, opencv

Hi I have the magnitude spectrum after a FFT operation on an image now I want to draw a mask. However using hough line etc, I am getting too many lines and the mask fails. Here are links to the image and the mask that I need to create

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgbmf3ju50uf821/fftimg4.jpg?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ktl0yghan9t868o/image4.jpg?dl=0

Thanks in advance

here is the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imshow, imsave, imread ,imsave
import mahotas


scaler = .5
img = imread("color2.jpeg")[:,:,:3]
mask = imread("image4.jpg")[:,:,:3]

img = cv2.resize(img, (0,0), fx=scaler, fy=scaler)
imggray = np.mean(img, -1)
imfft = np.fft.fft2(imggray)
mags = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
angles = np.angle(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
visual = np.log(mags)
visual2 = (visual - visual.min()) / (visual.max() - visual.min())*255
cv2.imshow('Visual 2', visual2.astype(np.uint8))

imsave('fftimg4.jpg',visual2)

height,width,depth = img.shape
masking = np.zeros((height,width))

vis = visual2.astype(np.uint8)
edges = cv2.Canny(vis,50,180)
cv2.imshow('Gradient', edges)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,200,200,10)
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
   a = np.cos(theta)
   b = np.sin(theta)
   x0 = a*rho
   y0 = b*rho
   x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
   y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
   x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
   y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

   cv2.line(masking,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),1)

   cv2.imshow('HoughLines', masking)

   mask = (np.mean(mask,-1) > 20)
   visual[mask] = np.mean(visual)
   newmagsshift = np.exp(visual)
   newffts = newmagsshift * np.exp(1j*angles)
   newfft = np.fft.ifftshift(newffts)
   imrev = np.fft.ifft2(newfft)
   newim2 = 255 - np.abs(imrev).astype(np.uint8)
   imsave("fftimg2.jpg",  newim2  )

   cv2.imshow('Image without Lines', newim2.astype(np.uint8))

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow, you will be better received if you explicitly state your problem and provide source code showing your attempt at a solution.

Comment: Maybe try reducing the granularity of your Hough space, so you get fewer lines output. So rather than say 1 degree of granularity, have fewer `bins` in your Hough space corresponding to 3 or 5 degrees.

Comment: Noted @ msanti  here is the original image https://www.dropbox.com/s/kiox2jcnxtkpg15/color2.jpeg?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

First, please, clarify. In fft you have at least three 'vertical' lines and a bunch of 'horizontal', is that correct? also, do you really need to automate this, or this filtering might be done manually? Does your hough line algorithm gives you bunch of equations for lines?

It seems you can filter out those lines that go through zero, as that is what you expect. Go through zero and also closest to expected angle (like -5 deg in your example).

Comment: to be more accurate it is fft2. I have added the code to the original message

Comment: still doesn't answer following: 1) how automated it should be, can you tolerate user choosing correct mask out of options? 2) If not, how similar 2D-FFTs are for different samples, can you pre-select types (say, angle) of lines you are really looking for? 2.1) why don't you just pick the longest line out of options and roll with that?

Comment: It should be fully automated as this feeds into another module. No it cannot be user drive as I am using it to remove the ruled lines on a paper on which some images are present the mask will be different for every page scanned, if you run my code you will get multiple lines which are as long at different angles